# Bash check while read no lines found

Tags: bash

I have the following loop in bash:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep somewifi | while read -r line; do
```

which checks for all wifi with "somewifi" in it and do something.  How do I exit program if the grep somewifi comes out to empty i.e. not found

Comment: BTW, if you really just want to check if it's present, without processing the specific line where a match is found, then `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep -q scanwifi || exit 1` would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- NOT /bin/sh

target=somewifi

found=0
while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line = *"$target"* ]]; then
    echo "Doing something with $line"
    found=1
  fi
done < <(sudo iwlist wlan0 scan)

if (( found == 0 )); then
  echo "$target not found" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

What we're doing here is avoiding [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) by executing the `while` loop in the main shell, not a subshell (as would be created by piping into the `while read` loop). This lets us set variables inside the loop that still persist after it exits.

Comment: It's not good if you want to retain state. Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 for details.

Comment: I found that on the internet I didnt come up with that.

Comment: Might have been written by someone accustomed to ksh -- there, the last element of a pipeline is executed in the primary shell by default, so you can set variables and they'll be available later. It's *sometimes* possible to do that in very new versions of bash, but the feature is a bit quirky (has to be explicitly enabled, and even then only works in shells with job control turned off).

Comment: why not /bin/bash on the top btw?

Comment: @bakalolo You can refer to this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my) for explanation on that point.

Comment: To add to the great link from PesaThe -- on MacOS in particular, the vendor-provided `/bin/bash` is an ancient 3.x release, but Bash 4 is often installed via MacPorts or Homebrew; using `#!/usr/bin/env bash` ensures that any version the user has installed in preference to the vendor's is used.